# Not able to connect aws redis with ec2 on same VPC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have created AWS ElastiCache redis server and configured with EC2 instance, but somehow I am not able to connect Redis via EC2 instance.

I have assigned the same security group as well.

here is my configuration

[image: EC2]

[image: Redis]

Error I am facing is `Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on some-prod.dhgdjw.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379 (Redis::TimeoutError)`

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you tried proposed answer? or let me know if still issue exist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you mention the same security group where you do not need such a setting. You Redis SG should be different it just suggestion as you need it on your local VPC.

Verify Few things...

Go you **ElastiCache Dashboard**

Select the Redis and click on the cluster then click on modify

[image]

then you will see security group attach with this Cluster You can attach one or many group with this cluster.

[image]

click on the edit icon and verify does it allow trafic on 6379 from `10.0.0.1/16` If instance and redis in same VPC, if not then allow public IP of instance in redis SG.

[image]

and you can allow also your public IP to check if it accessible. Install redis-client and try this command.

```
redis-cli -h some-prod.dhgdjw.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com ping

PONG
```

If ping pong working its mean SG allow traffic.

Comment: Hey, @Adiii Thanks for reply

Comment: I followed your steps but issue is still there.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as your answer did the trick. finally `0.0.0.0/0` on port 6379 work for me.

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay welcome bro but do not make it public 0.0.0.0/0 at production its not good practice. try to figure out ec2 IP and whitelist that IP only.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will figure it out and do same. again thanks for your support.

Comment: you can keep that within vpc and expose it all machines in vpc